# shadow Selenium and CSS python

Tags: python, css, selenium-webdriver

Boa tarde pessoal, sou iniciante total em programação e estou fazendo algumas automações e travei em uma que esta usando shadow e não tenho conhecimento suficiente para resolver este problema. Se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço!

[image: Foto do Codigo da pagina]

Segue códigos que já tentei e não consegui selecionar o nome "DE SEGS LTDA"

Tentativa 1 Selecionar via Xpath (Sem Sucesso)
wait_and_click(navegador, '(//ion-label[@id="ion-rb-0-lbl"])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX9Ob.png)')

Tentativa 2 Selecionar via css (Sem Sucesso) Pode ser que eu não esteja usando da forma certa, sou novato total com isso

element = navegador.find_element_by_css_selector("label[for='ion-rb-0']")
element.click()

Tentativa 3 Selecionar via shadow e css (Sem Sucesso) Pode ser que tb não esteja usando da forma certa, sou novato total com isso

shadow = Shadow(navegador)
element = shadow.find_element("label[for='ion-rb-0']")
element.click()

Já gostaria de agradecer a todos pelo tempo e a paciência destinada aqui na plataforma e que sempre me ajuda muito, com muitos aprendizados!!! Valeu pessoal

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SO-PT! Para facilitar a ajuda, recomendo que você leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1). Está difícil entender o que você precisa.

Comment: Ola @rtheodoro, obrigado por sinalizar que não fui claro. Objetivamente eu preciso clicar dentro daquele dropbox que aparece na imagem e anexo. Clicar em DE SEGS LTDA só que ele esta dentro de shadow-root é isso que preciso e não tenho ideia de como fazer! se puder me ajuda eu agradeço